# Compare JS files and pick according to requirement

Tags: python, regex

**Problem Statement:**

1. Extract the filename and read if filename has jQuery on it, put them aside.
2. Second step will be to check one more and see if any jQuery files has `ui` in the filename.

**Input:**

```
script_ref1 = """<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/abc_bsub.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/abc_core.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/abc_explore.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/abc_qaa.js"/>"""
```

OR

```
script_ref2 = """<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/abc_bsub.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/abc_core.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/abc_explore.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/abc_qaa.js"/>"""
```

And:

```
div_attr_info = {"data-js":"jquery-1.8.1.min.js, jquery-ui-1.2.min.js, custom1.js, custom2.js"}
```

**Output:**

for script_ref1

```
doc_js: [' custom1.js', ' custom2.js']
```

for script_ref2

```
doc_js: [' jquery-ui-1.2.min.js', ' custom1.js', ' custom2.js']
```

**Algorithm:**

1. Set `jquery_flag` and `jquery_ui_flag` flag to `False`.
2. Extracting specific src attributes from script tags.
3. Iterate on step2 result.
4. Set `jquery_flag` to True because `jquery` is substring in the file list.
5. Check `ui` is substring or not. and set `jquery_ui_flag` according to it.
6. Get JS file list from the dictionary for comparison.
7. Iterate and Do comparison.
8. Print result.

Can the code be improved or optimized? Can I reduce the runtime?

```
jquery_flag = False
jquery_ui_flag = False
for ii in re.findall('src="js/([^"]*jquery[^"]*)"', script_ref):
    jquery_flag = True
    if "ui" in ii:
        jquery_ui_flag = True

tmp = div_attr_info["data-js"].split(",")
doc_js = []

for ii in tmp:
    if jquery_ui_flag and "jquery" in ii:
        pass
    elif jquery_flag and not jquery_ui_flag and "jquery" in ii and "ui" not in ii:
        pass
    else:
        doc_js.append(ii)

print "doc_js:", doc_js
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than performance, I suggest tackling readability first.

- **Put code in a function:** Figure out what it is that the code is trying to do, and package it in a function.  This also forces you to assign a name that summarizes its purpose.  It also forces you to define what the inputs and outputs are.  A docstring would also be tremendously helpful.
- **Use better variable names:** There is *always* a more descriptive name than `tmp`.  The dummy iteration variable `ii` is weird too — is it some kind of integer?  Also, variables named `something_flag` tend to indicate excessively procedural thinking.
- **Avoid procedural loops:**  In Python, loops of the form

  > ```
  > some_list = []
  > for element in iterable:
  >     if condition(element):
  >         some_list.append(element)
  > ```

  are better expressed using list comprehensions:

  ```
  some_list = [element for element in iterable if condition(element)]
  ```

  Also, loops of the form

  > ```
  > flag = False
  > for element in iterable:
  >     if condition(element):
  >         flag = True
  >         break
  > ```

  are better written using [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any).
- **Use regular expressions effectively:**  Instead of `"jquery" in ii and "ui" not in ii`, use a regular expression with a negative lookahead assertion.

  `div_attr_info["data-js"].split(",")` is a bit sloppy, in that it leaves leading spaces (but not consistently).  Use `re.split(r',\s*', …)` instead.

### Suggested solution

```
import re

def deduplicate_jquery(want_scripts, have_scripts=[]):
    """
    Return a copy of want_scripts, omitting any redundant mentions of "jquery"
    and "jquery-ui" if they are already listed in have_scripts.
    """
    jquery_ui = re.compile(r'jquery-ui\b')
    jquery = re.compile(r'jquery(?!-ui)\b')

    have_jquery_ui = any(jquery_ui.match(s) for s in have_scripts)
    have_jquery = have_jquery_ui or any(jquery.match(s) for s in have_scripts)

    return [
        want for want in want_scripts if
            not (have_jquery_ui and jquery_ui.match(want)) and
            not (have_jquery and jquery.match(want))
    ]

doc_js = deduplicate_jquery(
    re.split(r',\s*', div_attr_info["data-js"]),
    [m.group(1) for m in re.finditer(r'src="js/([^"]*)"', script_ref)]
)
print 'doc_js:', doc_js
```

Comment: Thank you, I will update code. and again past in question.

Answer (score 4):

Since your post is a little unclear to me, I'm just going to point out a few small things that could be improved quiet a bit.

- The program logic could be separated out into different functions. This allows for easy re-usability.
- You should flesh out this program with comments for clarity. There are two types of comments, regular comments, and docstrings. Regular comments start with a `#` character, followed by a description. Docstrings describe functions and classes, like so.

---

```
def my_function(args):
    """
    This is a docstring. Put a description
    of your function here.
    """
    ...


class MyClass(object):
    """
    Put a description of your class here.
    """
    ...
```

---

- You have some bad variable names, like `ii`, or `tmp`. Variable names should generally describe what the variable's purpose is.

There's not much for me to review, but if you want me to cover anything else, just mention it in the comments, and I'll see if I can cover it.